# What is the container data type in redis?

Tags: redis, container-data-type

I wast trying to store some data  into redis use below code

```
>>> r.zadd('metric:tag1:tag2:tag3:tag4', 1539870365, '0')
0
```

I am using pyredis as the client.

My understanding to above code is that

1. I create a key 'metric:tag1:tag2:tag3:tag4'
2. The value is 0
3. The value has a score 1539870365

But when I open my GUI redis client. I can see the  GUI identify  the data type as container.

And the  key of the container is metric.

The container  seems a nested object which has  a second level key tag1

So  what  is the container data type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your UI is playing tricks with you by processing the key's name, splitting by the colon and presenting you with a falsified nested view. You are correct in your understanding.